# How to simultaneously capture external command output and print it to the terminal

Tags: powershell, terminal, tee

Can I pipe back from:

```
$OUTPUT = $(flutter build ios --release --no-codesign | tail -1)
```

I would like to get both the last line from the build AND show progress, something like

```
$OUTPUT = $(flutter build ios --release --no-codesign | out | tail -1)
```

where the hypothetical `out` utility would also send the output to the terminal.

Do you know how?

Comment: That should work as is in osx or linux, even without the `$( )`, assuming there's an out command.

Comment: @js2010 `$VAR=...` is a syntax error in bash, variable names in assignments must not be preceded by a dollar sign (the spaces would also be problematic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:

- On **Unix**-like platforms, with **external-program output**, [js2010's elegant `tee /dev/tty` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59972291/45375) is the simplest.
- The **solutions below**, which **also work on Windows**, may be of interest for **processing *external-program* output line by line** in PowerShell.
- A ***general* solution** that also works with the *complex objects*  that PowerShell-native commands can output, **requires different approaches**:

  - In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, use the following:

    ```bash
    # PS v7+ only. Works on both Windows and Unix
    ... | Tee-Object ($IsWindows ? '\\.\CON' : '/dev/tty')
    ```

    - [GitHub issue #19827](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19827) is a green-lit, but as yet (as of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.x) unimplemented improvement  that will allow simplifying
      `($IsWindows ? '\\.\CON': '/dev/tty')` to `-Host`.
  - In *Windows PowerShell*, where [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object) unfortunately doesn't support targeting `CON`, a *proxy function* that utilizes `Out-Host` is required - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71040823/45375).

---

A *PowerShell* solution (given that the code in your question is PowerShell<sup>[1]</sup>):

I'm not sure how `flutter` reports its progress, but the following may work:

If everything goes to *stdout*:

```bash
$OUTPUT = flutter build ios --release --no-codesign | % {
  Write-Host $_ # print to host (console)
  $_  # send through pipeline
} | select -Last 1
```

<sup>Note: `%` is the built-in alias for [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), and `select` the one for [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object).</sup>

If progress messages go to *stderr*:

```bash
$OUTPUT = flutter build ios --release --no-codesign 2>&1 | % {
  Write-Host $_.ToString() # print to host (console)
  if ($_ -is [string]) { $_ }  # send only stdout through pipeline
} | select -Last 1
```

---

<sup>[1] As evidenced by the `$` sigil in the variable name *in the LHS of an assignment* and the spaces around `=`

(`$OUTPUT =` ), neither of which would work as intended in `bash` / POSIX-like shells.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean bash because to my knowledge there is no `tail` in powershell.

Here's how you can see a command's output while still capturing it into a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

# redirect the file descriptor 3 to 1 (stdout)
exec 3>&1

longRunningCmd="flutter build ios --release --no-codesign"

# use tee to copy the command's output to file descriptor 3 (stdout) while 
# capturing 1 (stdout) into a variable
output=$(eval "$longRunningCmd" | tee >(cat - >&3) )

# last line of output
lastline=$(printf "%s" "$output" | tail -n 1)

echo "$lastline"
```

Comment: Hopefully the OP will clarify, but the code in the question is PowerShell; while PowerShell itself has no `tail` command, running PowerShell _Core_ (v6+) on macOS or Linux allows you to use the standard `tail` utility, and even on Windows there are `tail` ports available.

Answer (score 1):

I use write-progress in the pipeline.
In order to keep readable pipeline, I wrote a function

> function Write-PipedProgress{
> <#
>
> ```
> .SYNOPSIS
>     Insert this function in a pipeline to display progress bar to user
>
> .EXAMPLE
>     $Result = (Get-250Items | 
>         Write-PipedProgress -PropertyName Name -Activity "Audit services" -ExpectedCount 250 |
>         Process-ItemFurther)
> ```
>
> ## >
>
> ```
> [cmdletBinding()]
> param(
>     [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
>     $Data,
>     [string]$PropertyName=$null,
>     [string]$Activity,
>     [int]$ExpectedCount=100
>     )
>
> begin {
>     Write-Verbose "Starting $($MyInvocation.MyCommand)"
>     $ItemCounter = 0
> }
> process {
>     Write-Verbose "Start processing of $($MyInvocation.MyCommand)($Data)"
>
>     try {
>         $ItemCounter++
>         # (3) mitigate unexpected additional input volume"
>         if ($ItemCounter -lt $ExpectedCount) {
>             $StatusProperty = if ($propertyName) { $Data.$PropertyName } > > else { ""}
>             $StatusMessage = "Processing $ItemCounter th $StatusProperty"
>             $statusPercent = 100 * $ItemCounter / $ExpectedCount
>             Write-Progress -Activity $Activity -Status $StatusMessage -> > PercentComplete $statusPercent
>         } else {
>             Write-Progress -Activity $Activity -Status "taking longer than expected" -PercentComplete 99
>         }
>
>         # return input data to next element in pipe
>         $Data
>     
>     } catch {
>         throw
>     }
>     finally {
>         Write-Verbose "Complete processing of $Data in > $($MyInvocation.MyCommand)"
>     }
>
> }
> end {
>     Write-Progress -Activity $Activity -Completed
>     Write-Verbose "Complete $($MyInvocation.MyCommand) - processed $ItemCounter items"
> }
> ```
>
> }

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would work, at least in osx or linux powershell (or even Windows Subsystem for Linux) that have these commands available.  I tested it with "ls" instead of "flutter".  Is there actually an "out" command?

```
$OUTPUT = bash -c 'flutter build ios --release --no-codesign | tee /dev/tty | tail -1'
```

Or, assuming tee isn't aliased to tee-object.  Actually, tee-object would work too.

```
$OUTPUT = flutter build ios --release --no-codesign | tee /dev/tty | tail -1
```

It would work with the $( ) too, but you don't need it.  In powershell, it's used to combine multiple pipelines.