# Can you redirect Tee-Object to standard out?

Tags: powershell, terminal, windows-console, tee

I am writing a script and I want to pass the values but also see them displayed

```
Get-Content data.txt | Tee-Object | data_processor.exe
```

But [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7.2) always requests a file and I just want to see it on the screen.

Comment: Not really what `Tee-Object` does, though I can see why you'd think it should. You probably have to replace it with `ForEach-Object{Write-Host $_; $_}` instead and run everything through a loop.

Comment: `data_processor.exe` needs all the lines of input (only four actually) at once, each line isn't independent.

Comment: The loop won't affect that, but if you want all four lines at once you should be using the `-raw` switch on `Get-Content`. That will read the entire file, then it can be passed to the `ForEach-Object` loop where all four lines will be written to the host and passed at once to `data_processor.exe`. Or wrap everything before `| data_processor.exe` in parenthesis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can output to a variable instead of a file:

```sh
Get-Content data.txt | Tee-Object -Variable data | data_processor.exe
$data  # Output
```

This passes content to "data_processor.exe" and stores it in variable `$data`. Data will be shown only when the .exe has finished.

Use `ForEach-Object` to examine output of `Get-Content` before each line is being send to the .exe:

```sh
Get-Content data.txt | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_   # Output line to console
    $_              # Forward line to next command in chain 
} | data_processor.exe
```

This pattern could be made more succinct and reusable, by writing a small [filter function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions#filters):

```sh
Filter Write-HostAndForward {
    Write-Host $_   # Output line to console
    $_              # Forward line to next command in chain    
}
```

Now we can write:

```sh
Get-Content data.txt | Write-HostAndForward | data_processor.exe
```

**Remarks:**

While `Write-HostAndForward` works for simple input, like strings received from `Get-Content`, for complex objects it typically doesn't produce the same output as we normally see in the console. That is because `Write-Host` simply converts the input to string using the `.ToString()` method, which skips PowerShells rich formatting system.

You might be tempted to simply replace `Write-Host` by `Out-Host`, but as [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) explains, it would format the input objects individually, which will produce a header for each object for table-formatted output. To avoid that, [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71040823/7571258) shows different ways to produce the expected formatted output.

Answer (score 9):

To complement [zett42's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71039685/45375):

If you're running **[PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, you can **pass the file path that represents the *terminal* (console)** to the (positionally implied) `-FilePath` parameter (in *Windows PowerShell*, this causes an error, unfortunately - see bottom section):

```bash
# PowerShell 7+ only

# Windows
Get-Content data.txt | Tee-Object \\.\CON | data_processor.exe

# Unix-like platforms (Linux, macOS)
Get-Content data.txt | Tee-Object /dev/tty | data_processor.exe

# Platform-agnostic
# See coming future improvement below (-Host)
Get-Content data.txt | Tee-Object ($IsWindows ? '\\.\CON': '/dev/tty') | data_processor.exe
```

Note:

- [GitHub issue #19827](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19827) is a green-lit, but as yet (as of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.x) unimplemented improvement  that will allow simplifying
  `($IsWindows ? '\\.\CON': '/dev/tty')` to `-Host`.

This **passes all data through while also printing it to the terminal (console), richly formatted, as usual, *as it becomes available*** - unlike with the `Tee-Object -Variable` approach, which requires collecting all output in memory first (which is a concern both in terms of output timing and memory consumption).

---

***Windows PowerShell* solution**: Custom [proxy (wrapper) function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375) **`Tee-Host`** wraps [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host) while also passing its input through; use it *instead* of `Tee-Object`:

```bash
function Tee-Host {  
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $InputObject
  )

  begin
  {
    $scriptCmd = { Out-Host }
    $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
    $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
  }
  
  process
  {
    # Pass to Out-Host, and therefore to the host (terminal)
    $steppablePipeline.Process($InputObject)
    # Pass through (to the success stream)
    $InputObject 
  }
  
  end
  {
    $steppablePipeline.End()
  }
    
}
```

- In effect, `Tee-Host` behaves like `Tee-Object \\.\CON` / `Tee-Object /dev/tty` in PowerShell 7+, where `Tee-Host` works too.
- Even in PowerShell 7+ `Tee-Host` may be preferable, because it uses *colored* output *unconditionally*, whereas the coloring behavior of `Tee-Object \\.\CON` / `Tee-Object /dev/tty` depends on the value of [`$PSStyle.OutputRendering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psstyle)

It is the use of a proxy function with a steppable pipeline wrapping `Out-Host` that ensures that the to-host formatted output looks the same as when the input is directly sent to the host.