# Running invoke-sqlcmd and storing the print output into a variable

Tags: powershell

I am running a SQL stored procedure via invoke-sqlcmd, having read the posts on [Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd capture verbose output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511498/powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-capture-verbose-output) and  [How to run a PowerShell script with verbose output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324882/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-with-verbose-output).

I have a working solution, however I am struggling with a tweak so that the solution can be complete. It currently prints onto the console, I only want the output to be in a variable and no console output. I have also toyed with the idea of setting `$VerbosePreference = "SilentlyContinue"` to no avail.

Here is what I have.

`$null = invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "DB_Server" -Database "DB" -Query "sp_storedProcedure_with_prints" -OutputSQLErrors $true -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable error_var -verbose 4>&1 | Tee-Object -variable script_output_variable`

It works, it does what I want it to do which is to save the script output in the variable $script_output_variable what is happening now is that the hundreds of lines that the stored procedure outputs is not required, especially when the script runs on thousands of servers.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is that `$script_output_variable` contains a bunch of verbose records you don't actually want... Have you tried _not_ adding `-Verbose` to the command? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redirecting verbose output to the success output stream (`4>&1`), which means a variable assignment (`$var = ...`) is sufficient to capture both the success output and the verbose output *without producing display output*.

By contrast, the very purpose of [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object) is to *also* produce display output / pass success output *through*.

Therefore the solution is *not* to use `Tee-Object` and to directly assign to the variable of interest:

```
$script_output_variable = invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "DB_Server" -Database "DB" -Query "sp_storedProcedure_with_prints" -OutputSQLErrors $true -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable error_var -verbose 4>&1
```

---

As an aside: In the event that you *do* want to capture output in a variable *while also passing it through*, enclosing an assignment in `(...)` is a simpler alternative to using `Tee-Object`; e.g.,

`($var = Get-Date)` is equivalent to - and faster than -
`Get-Date | Tee-Object -Variable var`

If your command produces many output objects and you want to retain streaming behavior, use the [common `-OutVariable` (`-ov`) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-outvariable); e.g.,

`Get-ChildItem -ov var | ...`

`Tee-Object`:

- is primarily useful when pass-through data is to also be captured in a *file*, e.g. 
  `Get-Date | Tee-Object -LiteralPath out.txt`
- in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* you may also use it to pass data through to the *display* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71040823/45375).