# Out-File Of ForEach With If(Test-Path ...)

Tags: powershell, foreach, export-csv

```
$homefolder = (gci \\SERVER\homefolder | select fullname)
$outfile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Homefolder_Desktop_Redirect.csv"
ForEach ($dir in $homefolder)
{If(Test-Path ($dir.FullName +"\Desktop")){write-host $dir.Fullname" contains desktop" -ForegroundColor Yellow
"{0:N2} GB" -f ((Get-ChildItem $dir.fullname -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1GB)
}}
ForEach ($dir in $homefolder)
{If(Test-Path ($dir.FullName +"\Desktop")){}else{write-host $dir.Fullname" does not contain desktop" -ForegroundColor Red
"{0:N2} GB" -f ((Get-ChildItem $dir.fullname -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1GB)
}}
```

I'm trying to get this to output to a file.  If I put the pipe between the last 2 `}}` or after the last `}` (in each Foreach), I'm told it's empty.  If I put IF inside another set of parentheses, like `{(If` I get If isn't valid.

If I try to write/append after `1GB)` my outfile is just my script.

If I try making the `Foreach($dir in $homefolder)` a variable, the `in` is an unexpected token.

I'm sure this is something simple, but I haven't used PowerShell for much in the last 5 years... assistance is appreciated.

---UPDATE---

Thanks for the help, all!

This is what I have thanks to the assistance I've received.

```
$outfile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Homefolder_Desktop_Redirect.txt"
Write-Output "Contains desktop:" | Set-Content $outfile -Force
(Get-ChildItem \\SERVER\homefolder).FullName | ForEach-Object {
    if(Test-Path (Join-Path $_ -ChildPath Desktop)) {
        Write-Host "$_ contains desktop" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        "$_ [{0:N2} GB]" -f (
        (Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse |
            Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        ).Sum / 1GB)
        }
} | Add-Content $outfile -Force
Write-Output "Contains NO desktop:" | Add-Content $outfile -Force
(Get-ChildItem \\SERVER\homefolder).FullName | ForEach-Object {
    if(Test-Path (Join-Path $_ -ChildPath Desktop)) {}
    else{
        Write-Host "$_ contains no desktop" -ForegroundColor Red
        "$_ [{0:N2} GB]" -f (
        (Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse |
            Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        ).Sum / 1GB)
        }
} | Add-Content $outfile -Force

Invoke-Item $outfile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason why PowerShell complains is because you're looking to pipe after a [language keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.2) which is simply not possible. You can however, use [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2), a cmdlet designed to enumerate input objects from pipeline, and because it is a [**cmdlet**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview?view=powershell-7.2) and **not a statement ([`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.2))**, you can pipe other cmdlets to it:

```bash
(Get-ChildItem \\SERVER\homefolder).FullName | ForEach-Object {
    if(Test-Path (Join-Path $_ -ChildPath Desktop)) {
        Write-Host "$_ contains desktop" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "$_ does not contain desktop" -ForegroundColor Red
    }

    $output = "$_ [{0:N2} GB]" -f (
        (Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse |
            Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        ).Sum / 1GB)
    # send output to the host
    Write-Host $output
    # send output to the success stream
    $output
} | Set-Content path\to\export.txt
```

Comment: Thanks!  I wrote 2 loops so directories with content I wanted show up first.

Comment: The only issue I have now is when I run the script, it no longer outputs the directory size onscreen.  Otherwise, with some additions, this is going to be my accepted solution.

Comment: @Nate I think my updated version should do it

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm good with what I have, after all.  Accepted solution.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you want to send the output from multiple statements to a single file, enclose them in `& { ... }` (or `. { ... }` to run directly in the caller's scope); a simplified example:

```
& {
  foreach ($i in 1..5)  { $i }
  foreach ($i in 6..10) { $i }
} | Out-File test.txt
```

However, you can reformulate your code to a *single pipeline*, using the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet* rather than the [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) loop *statement*:

```
$homefolder | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $hasDesktop = Test-Path (Join-Path $_.FullName Desktop)
    Write-Host ('{0} {1} desktop' -f $_.FullName, ('does not contain', 'contains')[$hasDesktop]) -ForegroundColor ('Red', 'Yellow')[$hasDesktop]
    'Contains {0}desktop' -f ('NO ', '')[$hasDesktop]
    '{0:N2} GB' -f ((Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1GB)
  } |
  Out-File $outfile
```

Note:

- Note the technique of letting a Boolean variable `$hasDesktop` select one of two values from an array, e.g., `('Red', 'Yellow')[$hasDesktop]`, which allows you to make do with a *single* `Write-Host` call to cover both the has-desktop and doesn't-have-desktop case.

  - This acts similar to the [ternary conditional operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false), available in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* only; that is, the above is equivalent to: 
    `($hasDesktop ? 'Yellow' : 'Red')`
  - The output string is pieced together with the help of `-f`, the [format operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f).
- As for your desire to print the calculated size to the display *as well*:

  - In *Windows PowerShell*, capture it in a variable first, write its value to the display with `Write-Host`, then output it to the success stream, as shown in [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74131523/45375).
  - In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, you can simply pipe to `Tee-Object CON`, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71040823/45375).