# How do I get Read-Host to show prompt question when containing script is assigned to variable?

Tags: powershell, user-interface, variables, scripting, user-input

I have a script to call an API endpoint to retrieve data from a hierarchy in an application.

This hierarchy has a few levels: Campus, Building, Floor
To make it user friendly, I've written the script to compile a table which gets the names of the hierarchy level being queried into an array, and adds a number to the entry in a new array column (basically the array index, made human-readable)

The script writes the table to the terminal using a `Format-Table` command, and then asks the user with a `Read-Host` command to provide an input based on the prompt provided.

If I then call this script assigning it to a variable (to make the output manipulation easier) the prompt doesn't show, so you can provide values blindly and not achieve what you want.

For example, if I call the script directly I get this in the terminal window:

```
.\My-script-here.ps1


Number name
------ ----
     1 Campus 1
     2 Campus 2

Enter number of campus:
```

If I assign it to a variable, I get this:

```
$variable = .\My-script-here.ps1

Enter number of campus:
```

Is there a way to get the compiled table to appear when assigning the script to the variable?
Currently the line in the script is `$Table | Format-Table -Property Number,Name`
I've tried piping this to `Write-Output` but that hasn't made a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the table with proper formatting to the *display only*, use [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Out-Host):

A simplified example:

```bash
[PSCustomObject]@{
  Foo = 'Bar'
  Baz = 42
} | 
  Format-Table |
  Out-Host

Read-Host 'Enter number of campus'
```

The above prints the formatted table directly to the host display (only), and is therefore not captured by the `$variable = …` assignment and prints *unconditionally* - only the `Read-Host` response will be captured.

---

If you want to *also* output the table *as data*, so that it is captured in `$variable`,  [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) enables a convenient [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Tee-Object) solution, with `CON` (on Windows) / `/dev/tty` (on Unix) as the `-FilePath` argument (representing the console / terminal device):

```bash
# PowerShell 7+ only
[PSCustomObject]@{
  Foo = 'Bar'
  Baz = 42
} | Tee-Object -FilePath ($IsWindows ? '\\.\CON' : '/dev/tty')

Read-Host 'Enter number of campus'
```

Now the table both prints *and* is captured in `$variable` (along with the `Read-Host` response).

However, the solution relies on the data triggering *implicit* `Format-Table` formatting.
If your data would by default be presented in *list* format, for instance, you would need an *explicit* `Format-Table` call, which complicates matters:

- Unless you truly want to capture the *formatting instructions* that `Format-Table` emits, you must *avoid* its use for outputting *data* - **`Format-*` cmdlets should only be used to produce *display* output, not *data*** for programmatic processing - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for background information.
- In this case you'll need a two-step approach as described for Windows PowerShell below, even in PowerShell 7+.

Unfortunately, *Windows PowerShell* doesn't support `-FilePath CON`, so you need to either collect the output in a variable first and then output and pass it to `Out-Host` in two separate operations, or use the `Tee-Host` convenience function shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71040823/45375), which has the added advantage of *streaming* its output.

*Windows PowerShell* / `Format-Table` solution (non-streaming):

```bash
# Capture the data in an aux. variable 
# and *print* it to the display.
# Note: 
#  * $table = ... by design only captures the *data*, not the Format-Table output.
#  * Enclosing the assignment in (...) passes the value *through*.
(
  $table = 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      Foo = 'Bar'
      Baz = 42
    } 
) | Format-Table | Out-Host

# Now also *output* the data, so it can be captured.
$table

Read-Host 'Enter number of campus'
```

Comment: Thanks, @mklement0

I'm running PS version 5 (I know, but this is for work and it's a pain to get anything updated to something resembling modern), but I've used your answer to help me workout what I could do.


So, I've assigned the format-table output to another variable, and then called that piped to Out-Host.

Comment: Not sure I'm quite following, but perhaps I again didn't provide enough context

`$table` is obtained from an API call, but it contains a lot of 'non-human friendly' details, such as GUIDs, etc, so I used `Format-Table` and selected the appropriate columns to display them in the order I wanted (number, and then name)
The response to the `Read-Host` input is then fed back to the main array which contains all the generated details, which is then fed back into the script....

Am I still using things incorrectly?

Comment: @PhilipRoss, now it is I who isn't quite following, but I don't think we need to resolve this. My only point - of a general nature - was: what `$data | Format-Table` outputs isn't _data_ anymore; it is _objects that provide formatting instructions_ to PowerShell, and they're only useful for that. Thus, if you want to capture _data_, for later _programmatic processing_, never capture the output from `Format-*` calls.