# Write-output not showing after running PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

My PowerShell script:

```
          $result = foreach ($user in $list) {
              $samname = $user.SamAccountName 
              $manager = $user.Manager
              $name = $user.Name 
              $managername = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$manager'" | Select Name
                  if ($managername.Name -eq $manager) {
                      Write-Output "$manager exists in AD."
                      $dname = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$manager'" | Select DistinguishedName
                      Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$samname'" | Set-ADUser -Manager $dname
                  }
                  else {
                      Write-Warning "$manager does not exist in AD."
                  } 
          }
          $result | Out-File -FilePath C:\testfile.txt -Width 500
```

`$manager = $user.Manager` is a list of names from a file.
If `$manager` exists in AD, there will be a `write-output "$manager exists in AD."`

In order to find `$manager` in AD, I created the variable `$managername`, and wrote an `if ($managername.Name -eq $manager)`.

I am able to produce the write-warning in the console, but not write-output. However, in the txt file, it is the opposite. The write-output if message is listed in the txt file, but not the write-warning else message.

What do I write to produce both if and else messages in the console and also the txt file?

**Update:**
Based on the suggestions given, I tried:

I removed $result, replaced Write-Output and Write-Warning, and tested with both Write-Host, then Write-Information. It did not manage to send any message to the txt file:

```
          foreach ($user in $list) {
              $samname = $user.SamAccountName 
              $manager = $user.Manager
              $name = $user.Name 
              $managername = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$manager'" | Select Name
                  if ($managername.Name -eq $manager) {
                      $if = Write-Host "$manager exists in AD."
                      $dname = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$manager'" | Select DistinguishedName
                      Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$samname'" | Set-ADUser -Manager $dname
                  }
                  else {
                      $else = Write-Host "$manager does not exist in AD."
                  } 
          }
          $if, $else | Out-File -FilePath C:\testfile.txt -Width 500
```

Appending both if and else write-output messages to a variable shows up in the console, but nothing appeared in the txt file.

```
          foreach ($user in $list) {
              $samname = $user.SamAccountName 
              $manager = $user.Manager
              $name = $user.Name 
              $managername = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$manager'" | Select Name
                  if ($managername.Name -eq $manager) {
                      $if = Write-Output "$manager exists in AD."
                      $dname = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$manager'" | Select DistinguishedName
                      Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$samname'" | Set-ADUser -Manager $dname
                  }
                  else {
                      $else = Write-Output "$manager does not exist in AD."
                  } 
          }
          $if, $else | Out-File -FilePath C:\testfile.txt -Width 500
```

Both messages with write-output only will have both if and else messages in the console. How do I output the messages to a txt file though?

```
          foreach ($user in $list) {
              $samname = $user.SamAccountName 
              $manager = $user.Manager
              $name = $user.Name 
              $managername = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$manager'" | Select Name
                  if ($managername.Name -eq $manager) {
                      Write-Output "$manager exists in AD."
                      $dname = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$manager'" | Select DistinguishedName
                      Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$samname'" | Set-ADUser -Manager $dname
                  }
                  else {
                      Write-Output "$manager does not exist in AD."
                  } 
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

##### [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) writes the specified objects to the *pipeline*.

It does ***not** explicitly* write to the console!

In PowerShell, objects in the pipeline might be:

- **passed on (piped)** to a following [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview), e.g.:

```
  Write-Output "$manager exists in AD." |Next-Action
```

- **assigned** to a variable, e.g.:

```
  $result = Write-Output "$manager exists in AD."
```

- **by *default*** (*in case they aren't piped or assigned*), eventually displayed on the console

> `Note`
>
> The `Write-Output` cmdlet is usually not required as PowerShell sends any object that is ***not* piped** and ***not* assigned** down to the pipeline by default

To *explicitly* write to the console you might use the [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) or the [`Write-Information`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-information) cmdlet.

> `Note`
>
> Starting in Windows PowerShell 5.0, Write-Host is a wrapper for `Write-Information` This allows you to use `Write-Host` to emit output to the information stream. This enables the capture or suppression of data written using `Write-Host` while preserving backwards compatibility.

In your case, the pipeline is captured by the `result =` assignment and I guess you actually want to write to both the pipeline line *and* the console. For this, you might use the [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object) cmdlet which *saves the command output in a file or variable and also sends it down the pipeline*. To [print the output to console and use in the pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71040823/1701026)

```
Tee-Object -InputObject "$manager exists in AD." -FilePath ($IsWindows ? '\\.\CON': '/dev/tty')
```

Related: [`#19827` `Tee-Object` should have a `-Console` parameter](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19827)

Comment: I replaced the line "Write-Output "$manager exists in AD."" with Tee-Object "$manager exists in AD." -FilePath ($IsWindows ? '\\.\CON': '/dev/tty')  , but the error message says that  ? is an unexpected token

Comment: Apparently you are using *Windows* PowerShell which doesn't know `$IsWindows` and the **ternary if**, in that case you might simplify the command to just: `Tee-Object -InputObject "$manager exists in AD." -FilePath '\\.\CON'`

Answer (score 0):

Write-Host is what you're looking for, writes to the console, without having to capture anything.

```
Write-Host "$manager exists in AD."
$dname = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$manager'" | Select DistinguishedName
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$samname'" | Set-ADUser -Manager $dname
```

Comment: I guess that the OP also want to write to the pipeline. What else is the `$result =` for?

Comment: The way it's written, the result isn't printed, or saved anywhere, so I assume it's a throw away, but maybe they're trying to save data into a csv for later? But to write-output with the $result a different way still accomplishes the same thing. I'm operating off of KISS, so just write-host for the desired result.

Comment: Yes, my intention is to output both the if and else message to a txt file, and also have these if and else messages written in the console. I have already added the missing " $result | Out-File -FilePath C:\testfile.txt -Width 500 "