All my output not writing to the pipeline/screen, because Select-Object -Property persisting for multiple calls/lines/objects; `ft` turns it back on
So I believe I am having a problem with the default selection of properties to output to the pipeline and eventually the screen.
In a nutshell, the following code:
$obj1 = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{a='1a';b='1b' ; c='1c'}
$obj2 = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{a='2a';b='2b' ; d='2d'}
$obj1
$obj2 | select d

produces no output for $obj2.
This issue presents as a symptom "powershell not producing some of my output" which is true. Actually it IS producing output just for properties that are not in the object because there's a secret persistence of a Select-Object -Property call that persists from object to object, call to call, line to line. from one pipeline to the next.
The explanation, brief as it is, appears correct here:
question: https://serverfault.com/questions/540073/powershell-select-object-keeping-same-columns-throughout-script; answer: https://serverfault.com/a/540276
However that person does not suggest this is a bug in Microsoft Powershell. I wonder if this is a bug, or if there's something I'm missing.
EDIT: The duplicated post DOES have a full, clear explanation: Script has two variables when done, but when I pipe to SELECT-object only first one returns data to console
END EDIT.
A full explanation of all the weird unexpected behavior on object property output is below:
# test output weirdness
$obj1 = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{a='1a';b='1b' ; c='1c'}
$obj2 = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{a='2a';b='2b' ; d='2d'}
'outputting obj1 selects its property names which persist across calls:'
'==only shows obj1 properties (no ''d'')=='
$obj1
$obj2
$obj2 | select d
$obj2 | select *
$obj2 | select a,b,d
'==ft resets (shows all obj2 properties)=='
$obj2 | ft 
'==now this forces to only show obj2 properties (no ''c'')=='
$obj2
$obj1
$obj1 | select c
$obj1 | select *
$obj1 | select a,b,c
'==ft resets=='
$obj1 | ft 
'==now this forces only ''a''=='
$obj1 | select a
$obj1
$obj2
'==will not show b=='
$obj1 | select b
$obj2 | select b
'==select * still shows only a=='
$obj1 | select *
$obj2 | select *
'==ft resets=='
$obj1 | ft 
'==if you happen to select a unique_property that other objects do not have, nothing comes out=='
$objunique = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{unique_property='unique_value'}
$objunique
'==obj1=beg=='
$obj1
'==obj1=end=='
'==obj2=beg=='
$obj2
'==obj2=end=='
'==after another ft reset all properties can be shown again=='
$obj1 | ft 
'==Out-Default after every output and after every select fixes/resets it=='
$obj1 | Out-Default
$obj2 | Out-Default
$obj1 | select a | Out-Default
$obj2 | select b | Out-Default
$obj1 | select c | Out-Default
$obj2 | select d | Out-Default

'Even though help says (quote):'
# PowerShell automatically adds `Out-Default` to the end of every pipeline.
(get-help -full Out-Default).description.text[0].Substring(0,75)

# This cmdlet isn't intended to be used by the end user. 
(get-help -full Out-Default).description.text[2].Substring(0,55)
'Nowhere in Out-Default help does it say it somehow resets the default properties that are selected and output.'

''
'==Write-Host avoids the select issue but is not table by default==' | Write-Host
'==Write-Host can appear out of order=='
'==Write-Host can appear out of order==' | Write-Host
'==Write-Host=pipeline=beg==' | Write-Host
$obj1 | Write-Host
$obj2 | Write-Host
'==Write-Host=pipeline=end==' | Write-Host
Write-Host '==Write-Host=call=beg=='
Write-Host $obj1
Write-Host $obj2
Write-Host '==Write-Host=call=end=='

produces the output:
outputting obj1 selects its property names which persist across calls:
==only shows obj1 properties (no 'd')==

c  b  a 
-  -  - 
1c 1b 1a
   2b 2a
        
   2b 2a
   2b 2a
==ft resets (shows all obj2 properties)==



d  b  a 
-  -  - 
2d 2b 2a


==now this forces to only show obj2 properties (no 'c')==

d  b  a 
-  -  - 
2d 2b 2a
   1b 1a
        
   1b 1a
   1b 1a
==ft resets==



c  b  a 
-  -  - 
1c 1b 1a


==now this forces only 'a'==

a 
- 
1a
1a
2a
==will not show b==
  
  
==select * still shows only a==
1a
2a
==ft resets==



c  b  a 
-  -  - 
1c 1b 1a


==if you happen to select a unique_property that other objects do not have, nothing comes out==

unique_property
---------------
unique_value   
==obj1=beg==
               
==obj1=end==
==obj2=beg==
               
==obj2=end==
==after another ft reset all properties can be shown again==



c  b  a 
-  -  - 
1c 1b 1a


==Out-Default after every output and after every select fixes/resets it==

c  b  a 
-  -  - 
1c 1b 1a



d  b  a 
-  -  - 
2d 2b 2a



a 
- 
1a



b 
- 
2b



c 
- 
1c



d 
- 
2d


Even though help says (quote):
PowerShell automatically adds `Out-Default` to the end of every pipeline. `
This cmdlet isn't intended to be used by the end user. 
Nowhere in Out-Default help does it say it somehow resets the default properties that are selected and output.

==Write-Host avoids the select issue but is not table by default==
==Write-Host can appear out of order==
==Write-Host can appear out of order==
==Write-Host=pipeline=beg==
@{c=1c; b=1b; a=1a}
@{d=2d; b=2b; a=2a}
==Write-Host=pipeline=end==
==Write-Host=call=beg==
@{c=1c; b=1b; a=1a}
@{d=2d; b=2b; a=2a}
==Write-Host=call=end==

Posts with similar symptoms on the web but not this select problem:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/troubleshoot-powershell-script-output/
Troubleshoot PowerShell Script Output (Write-Host can not be redirected to an output text file.)

Write-output not showing after running PowerShell script (Write-Output writes to pipeline, not host (directly); powershell sends it to the host for you unless it's otherwise consumed by eg an assignment to variable; Whereas Write-Host writes to the console immediately. This long answer explains: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76512346/4582204)



Typically a script only returns one type of object.  Implied format-table is using the first object encountered to learn how to display it.  There are various workarounds, like using format-table many times or using format-list instead.

When Format-Table formatting is applied, which happens implicitly if an object has 4 or fewer properties and its type doesn't have associated formatting data, the first object in a collection (potentially even across multiple collections) locks in all display columns based on its properties. If subsequent objects have different properties, only those they share with the first one are displayed; if a given object shares none, a blank line is displayed. This is only a display problem, as you can verify by piping the objects to ... | Format-List.
See the linked duplicate for details.

Related: Not all properties displayed / #13906 Add -UnifyProperties parameter to Select-Object
